# What is lxsession?

Tags: lubuntu, session, lxde, lxsession

Running `lxsession` my appearance settings changed to something that looked like the `LXDE session` (while my normal session is `Lubuntu`).

Running `lxsession-edit` opens the `Desktop Sessions Settings` that allows to decide which programs should start automatically at login.

Running `lxsession-logout` opens the options to logout, shut down and so on.

In `/home/username/.config/lxsession` there are 2 directories (Lubuntu and LXDE) containing  a file called `desktop.conf`.

Can I save sessions in Lxsession, and does it have other options beside what its main definition states ("LXSession is the standard session manager used by LXDE. LXSession automatically starts a set of applications and sets up a working desktop environment")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have already quoted,

> LXSession is the standard session manager used by LXDE. LXSession automatically starts a set of applications and sets up a working desktop environment

This is it. The `lxsession` is the session starter and manager for standard LXDE desktop. But Lubuntu uses a customized version of LXDE session which is started by `startlubuntu` program.

The [manual page saying this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/lxsession.1.html)

> A session manager is used to automatically start a set of applications
>          and set up a working desktop environment. **Moreover, when the user
>          logout, it remembers the applications in use, and restart them the next
>          time you login.**

So, it is clear that lxsession can save session state.

Comment: so, no more than that: i mean the "management" aspect is limited to settings that can be made in Desktop Sessions Settings, without handling `different` sessions to save, etc, like in Xubuntu/Xfce and I guess in Ubuntu/Unity.  could i use a different session manager? would you consider answering the related question linked above?